# Using Zend-Console in Zend Framework 3 in XAMPP

Tags: php, shell, zend-framework3

I am running Zend Framework 3 on a local Windows machine with XAMPP 3.2.1. After installing the zend-console component, I have created a simple console route as well as an controller action in order to test the basic functionality by a request from the XAMPP shell.

However, I am not clear about starting the ZF app from there. The official documentation proclaims a "zf" command (https://github.com/zendframework/zend-console/blob/master/doc/book/intro.md), but this command is not accepted by the XAMPP shell.

How can I start the app in XAMPP from the shell? Do I have to create any alias (php public/index.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Zend-Console expects routes like command arguments.

So if you create a simple route `index` then it will work as `php public\index.php index`

Console apps doesn't require Apache or any other webserver to run because the main goal is to create scripts to run it in console with the php command line interface.